# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'watchlist' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I've been trying to submit an html form to spring boot but can't get it working.

I have this in my pom.xml

```
<!-- Enable JSP with Spring Boot  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have this in my application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I have created a jsp page in `<project-name>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`

At the very top of that page, I put

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

I also have a similar html file called index.html located in

```
<project-name>/src/main/resources/static/index.html
```

But the code doesn't seem to be recognizing the taglib because I see this in the web page:

[image]

Notice how the taglib is not recognized and just prints it at the top of the page?

So I delete the index.html page to force it to find the index.jsp file instead.  In that case I see the following error in the web page:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sun Oct 18 11:11:20 MDT 2020 There was an unexpected error
> (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Neither BindingResult nor
> plain target object for bean name 'watchlist' available as request
> attribute

Here is the part of the jsp file that sends the form:

```
<dialog id="favDialog">
   <form:form method="POST" action="/api/v1/AddSymbolToWatchlist" modelAttribute="watchlist">
      <form:label path="symbol">Enter Symbol:</form:label>
      <form:input path="symbol"/><br><br>
      <form:button>Add</form:button>
   </form:form>
</dialog>
```

My spring boot controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AddSymbolToWatchlist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSymbolToWatchlist(@Valid @ModelAttribute("watchlist") Watchlist watchlist,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error";
    }
    System.out.println("symbol="+watchlist.getSymbol());

    return watchlistService.addSymbolToWatchlist(watchlist);
}
```

The error seems to imply that I have already clicked the button that posts the request, but I haven't.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Per gtiwari333 response I changed the controller to look like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/AddSymbolToWatchlist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSymbolToWatchlist(@ModelAttribute("watchlist") Watchlist watchlist, Model m){
        String symbol = watchlist.getSymbol();
        System.out.println("symbol=" +symbol);
        Watchlist wlist = new Watchlist();
        wlist.setSymbol(symbol);
        m.addAttribute("msg", symbol +" was submitted.");
        m.addAttribute("watchlist", wlist);

        return "index";
    }

class Watchlist {
     String symbol;
     
     public String getSymbol() {
         return symbol;
     }
     public void setSymbol(String sym) {
         this.symbol = sym;
     }
}
```

And the popup form in index.jsp looks like this:

```
<dialog id="favDialog">
   <h2>Message: ${msg}</h2>
   <form:form method="POST" action="/api/v1/AddSymbolToWatchlist" modelAttribute="watchlist">
      <form:label path="symbol">Enter Symbol:</form:label>
      <form:input path="symbol"/><br><br>
      <form:button>Add</form:button>
   </form:form>
</dialog>
```

Comment: When you have `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` it won't treat HTML file JSP and process the tags

Comment: Can you add the request data that you are using for `/AddSymbolToWatchlist`? Most likely the request doesn't have `watchlist` parameter

Comment: `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'watchlist' available as request attribute` as this error says you don't have watchlist parameter on the request

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the form submit code.  I've done that now.  It does include watchlist model attribute.

Comment: Can you also show us the RequestMapping that returns the form view? I suspect that you are not returning an empty Watchlist object on your model. eg `m.addAttribute("watchlist", new Watchlist());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `modelAttribute="watchlist"` on your jsp, you must return the Model with attribute `watchlist` as following

```
 @GetMapping("/")
 String index(Model m) {
   // you should have this so that modelAttribute="watchlist" on jsp renders
   m.addAttribute("watchlist", new Watchlist()); 

   return "myjspform";
 }
```

Here's working code:

```
package soquestion64416269;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Ctrl {

    @GetMapping("/")
    String index(Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("msg", "Enter symbol and click Add");
        m.addAttribute("watchlist", new Watchlist());

        return "myjspform";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/AddSymbolToWatchlist")
    public String addSymbolToWatchlist(@ModelAttribute("watchlist") Watchlist watchlist, Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("msg", watchlist.getSymbol() + " was submitted. Now enter new symbol and click Add");
        m.addAttribute("watchlist", new Watchlist());

        return "myjspform";
    }
}

@Data
class Watchlist {
    String symbol;
}
```

myjspform.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<h2>Message: ${msg}</h2>

<form:form method="POST" action="/AddSymbolToWatchlist" modelAttribute="watchlist">
    <form:label path="symbol">Enter Symbol:</form:label>
    <form:input path="symbol"/><br><br>
    <form:button>Add</form:button>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  I added your code to the EDIT section in the post.  Unfortunately, still getting the same error.  Maybe I need to create a completely separate program like you did and gradually integrated it into my main code?

Comment: The key is the method with `GetMapping` that is called when the page is loaded  should have `m.addAttribute("watchlist", new Watchlist());` . I also added it on @PostMapping because I'm displaying the same html form after the form is submitted.

Comment: I added lombok to my dependencies so I could use the Data annotation and RequiredArgsConstructor annotation.  I copied and pasted your GetMapping code.  My PostMapping code now looks just like yours.  I created a "myjspform.jsp", cut and pasted your code into it, and saved it in the src>main>webapp>WEB-INF>views folder.  When I put localhost:8080/myjspform.jsp in the browser it shows: "JSP file [/myjspform.jsp] not found"

Comment: I finally got it working!  You were right.  I just had to change /AddSymbolToWatchlist to /api/v1/AddSymbolToWatchlist in your myjspform.jsp

Comment: My app is a single page app so I don't want a separate jsp page to be rendered.  I want to call the backend from a popup dialog and have the popup dialog render the response.  Could you point me to an example of how to do that?

Comment: `My app is a single page app so I don't want a separate jsp page to be rendered.` it depends on how are you rendering the HTML content for popup dialog. If that dialog HTML is server rendered you should be able to initialize it with Model attribute as I mentioned in the GetMapping.

Comment: Also, a side note: if you use a simple HTML form without JSP taglib you don't need to init the Model attribute in a new GetMapping. So, simple `<form method="POST" action="/AddSymbolToWatchlist">
    <input name="symbol"/><br><br>
    <button>Add</button>
</form>` works perfectly